# Quick, beginner MASM register question - DX:AX

Tags: assembly, masm, cpu-registers

I am currently studying for an exam I'll have on x86 assembly.

I didn't have much luck googling for ":", too common of a punctuation mark :/

> IDIV - Signed Integer Division
>
> Usage:   IDIV   src
>
> Modifies flags: (AF,CF,OF,PF,SF,ZF undefined)
>
> Signed binary division of accumulator by source.  If source is a
> byte value, AX is divided by "src" and the quotient is stored in
> AL and the remainder in AH.  If source is a word value, **DX:AX** is
> divided by "src", and the quotient is stored in AL and the
> remainder in DX.
>
> *Taken from "Intel Opcodes and Mnemonics"*

What does DX:AX mean?

Thanks a lot for your time :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a pair of registers: `DX` and `AX`.

The numerator itself is a double word. The upper word of the numerator should be stored at `DX`, the lower one in `AX`.

Answer (score 11):

`DX:AX` is the 32-bit value to use as the numerator of your division. The most significant 16 bits are held in `DX`, the least significant in `AX`. It's a way of specifying a 32-bit value in an otherwise 16-bit environment.